# No Wifi adapter found - HP Laptop - Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, drivers, realtek

I am beginner in Linux. I know that this question has been posted a lot, but even after following given solution(s) I am not able to install the required driver for my WiFi adaptor.

This is what I am getting on running the following commands 

lspci :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
```

iwconfig :

```
enp0s20f0u3  no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

lshw -C network :

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 80:ce:62:10:94:1c
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: enp0s20f0u3
       serial: ca:f1:2b:53:09:58
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.58 link=yes multicast=yes
```

It would be really helpful if someone could guide me in installing the correct driver.

 Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

We see **UNCLAIMED** for your wifi controller (Realtek Semiconductor d723) which means no driver has attached to it.

Since your Ubuntu is LTS maybe the kernel is old and does not have the driver.
Please run following commands and reboot.

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-firmware
```

More info for [HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) (Ubuntu Hardware Enablement)

Comment: I tried those commands but it didn't work. Infact I think I can't 
even boot my laptop now :/ Its showing some errors in dev/sda5

Comment: @nooborn it may happen after firmware update, please check https://askubuntu.com/a/838386/722342

Comment: ok, somehow I loaded ubuntu by going in "Advanced options for Ubuntu" (in the grub menu) inside which there was a list of options :    **Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-59-generic** ,  **Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-59-generic (recovery) mode** ,  **Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-101-generic** and  **Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-101-generic  (recovery mode)** .   First two dosen't work. Tried the third option and it worked. I think the kernel which was downloaded from the given commands was incompatible. Now I have to delete since it somehow got set as default kernel. Are there any means to delete it safely?

Comment: Finally, back to square one, I managed to unistall all the unecessary kernels as the OS is up and running but still the WiFi driver is not there. I am now thinking about updating Ubuntu 18 to 19, will it help me installing the required driver?